# Cloud watch logs prepending timestamp to each line

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have cloud watch log agent setup and the logs streamed are appending a timestamp to beginning of each line which we could see after export.

2017-05-23T04:36:02.473Z "message"

Is there any configuration on cloud watch log agent setup that helps not appending this timestamp to each log entry?
Is there a way to export cloud watch logs only the messages of log events? We dont want the timestamp on our exported logs.

Thanks

Comment: All CloudWatch Logs events have a timestamp associated with them.  If you don't want it to be exported, it will be have to be configured to do so with whatever tool you are using to export the events.  What are you using to export them?

Comment: We are exporting them to S3 using a Lambda function(create_export_task). The exported logs has timestamp beginning of every line. Could you suggest the ways to strip the timestamp in each log

Comment: Is it a Lambda function you wrote, or one you found elsewhere?  Perhaps you could update your question with a link to the code you're using if it's publicly available.  You probably need to modify the function to exclude the timestamp.

Comment: @user5556585 Have you solved your problem? How did you remove the timestamp in your lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are able to retrieve those logs using your **Lambda** function (Python 3.x).

Then you can use **Regular Expression** to identify the timestamp and write a function to strip it from the event log.

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z\t
```

The above will identify the following timestamp: **2019-10-10T22:11:00.123Z**

Here is a simple Python function:

```
def strip(eventLog):
    timestamp = "r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z\t'"
    result = re.sub(timestamp, "", eventLog)
    return result
```

Comment: This is the function to export CloudWatch log to s3. It doesn't have the interface to change each line. https://github.com/tensult/aws-automation/blob/master/export-cloudwatch-logs-to-s3/index.js

Comment: it's not helping what the question is asking for

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, I needed the same exact behavior you are asking for and looks like it's not possible unless you implement a man in the middle processor to remove the timestamp from every log message as suggested in the other answer

Checking the CloudWatch Logs Client API in the first place, it's **required** to send the timestamp with every log message you send to CloudWatch Logs ([API reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.put_log_events))

And the export logs to S3 task API also has no parameters to control this behavior ([API reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.create_export_task))